# When Excel stops you sorting, saying "Merged cells have to be identically sized", how do you find the merged cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel puts up this complaint when the range of cells you are trying to sort includes merged cells.

[image]

But if it's a large sheet how do you track down the merged cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit > Find > Format (specify merged cells) > Find All.

Or use a macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testme()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim resp As Long

    For Each myCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If myCell.MergeCells Then
            If myCell.Address = myCell.MergeArea(1).Address Then
                resp = MsgBox(prompt:="found: " _
                & myCell.MergeArea.Address & vbLf & _
                "Continue looking", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
                If resp = vbNo Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: years and years of using Excel and never before noticed (or used) Find, Format. Thanks.